# TypeOrm: ER_DUP_FIELDNAME: Duplicate column name in self referencing relationship

Tags: node.js, typescript, crud, nestjs, typeorm

I use NestJs with a Relationship that references itself (parent <-> child). I want to send a request which includes the parent in the response. (e.g. `/projects?join=parentProject`).

This works fine until I include a `limit` param (e.g. `/projects?join=parentProject&limit=10`). 
Than the request fails with this SQL error message:

`[Nest] 31189   - 01/12/2020, 4:18:44 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] ER_DUP_FIELDNAME: Duplicate column name 'parent_id' +3745ms`

I found out that the following query is send to the DB. The `parent_id` is not prefixed and so the duplicate column name occures.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `distinctAlias`.`Project_id` as "ids_Project_id"
FROM (SELECT `Project`.`id`         AS `Project_id`,
             `Project`.`name`       AS `Project_name`,
             `parentProject`.`id`   AS `parentProject_id`,
             `parentProject`.`name` AS `parentProject_name`,
             `Project`.`parent_id`,
             `parentProject`.`parent_id`
      FROM `project` `Project` LEFT JOIN `project` `parentProject` 
                               ON `parentProject`.`id` = `Project`.`parent_id`) `distinctAlias`
ORDER BY `Project_id` ASC
LIMIT 10
```

How can I fix this?

---

My NestJS controller looks like this:

```
@Crud({
  model: {
    type: Project,
  },
  query: {
    join: {
      parentProject: {},
    },
    alwaysPaginate: true,
  },
})
@Controller('projects')
export class ProjectController implements CrudController<Project> {

  constructor(
    public readonly service: ProjectService,
  ) {}
}
```

Here is my entity class:

```
@Entity()
export class Project {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  readonly id: number;

  @ManyToOne(type => Project, project => project.childProjects)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'parent_id' })
  parentProject: Project;

  @OneToMany(type => Project, project => project.parentProject)
  childProjects: Project[];
}
```

This is how my Database table looks like:

```
create table if not exists project
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    parent_id int null,
    name varchar(255) null,
)
engine=MyISAM charset=utf8;
```

---

Another info: If I query the projects manually it works fine.

```
this.service
  .find({
    relations: ['parentProject'],
    take: 10,
  });  // Works fine
```

So I guess it has to do something with the options inside `@Crud({})` decorator.